# adding images to table view swift

Tags: ios, swift

[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnhyj.png)

[uiimageview extension to load image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJWUV.png)

[Cell class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xwkG.png)

[cell loading in tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ril70.png)
Ive been trying to add images to my table view using these functions but for some reason the images wont show up it doesnt throw any errors and the url s are being passed in correctly since the print shows urls. Any help on why these photos wont show up would be massively appreciated

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include code as text, not images. Don't use `try ?`; use `do/try/catch` so that you can capture any exceptions that are thrown rather than just throwing them away. Also, although force downcasting is generally advised against, consensus is that `cellForRow(at:)` is one place where it is a good idea. Better to quickly catch the problem will cell dequeue during development. Cell dequeue can't suddenly fail and returning an empty `UITableViewCell` again just hides the issue.

Comment: Oh, and the red outline and red error arrow in your storyboard means that your constraints for the image view aren't right, so there is a chance your image view isn't even on screen

Comment: ‘Weak self’ in the closure returns an optimal. As a good practice, I think you should add guard ‘let self = self else { return }’ which safely unwrap the optimal sell.

Comment: I meant optional not optimal... anyway... Self may may be nil and give unexpected behaviors

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippets are correct. I think the only problem is that your UIImageView (userImage) is not constrained on the view in the Storyboard so it disappears every time the App is run.
What you need to do is Add New Constraints by typing the values:

[image]